# How does McMyAdmin handle whitelists?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How does popular Minecraft server admin tool [McMyAdmin](http://www.phonicuk.com/Software/McMyAdmin.aspx) handle whitelists?

The Preferences tab lists the following options for Whitelist Mode: No whitelisting, Match any group, and Lockdown. And does it use whitelist.txt to set these options?

Comment: Link to McMyAdmin is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No whitelisting** = Self explainatory

**Match any group** = Allow anyone who is assigned to a group to join

**Lockdown** = Allow anyone who is currently playing to continue playing but prevent any new connections.